# Want to fetch recently played songs in itunes within my application

Tags: ios, swift, itunes

Is there any way to fetch recently played songs in itunes within my custom application?

I want to display list of recently played songs in my application. Is there any API available for this? I did some R & D to do this task but not getting any satisfied answer.

If anyone has already did this task, please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Apple Music API has an endpoint for recently played. Apple Music and iTunes are tightly coupled, so I assume this works for your tracks that aren't played through Apple Music (so your local files in iTunes) but you would need to investigate that yourself.

Requires the user to be authenticated first.

How to do that:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/AppleMusicWebServicesReference/SetUpWebServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017625-CH2-SW1

But once thats done;

```
https://api.music.apple.com/v1/me/recent/played
```

Comment: I created all the keys mentioned in the link above. Now I am lil bit stuck here, what to do next? Do you have any sample code for this?

Comment: So now you need to get your users to authenticate with the service and get back a token that you can use to send subsequent requests. Using a networking library in your application such as AlamoFire will let you handle your session, send requests and do whatever you need to do the responses.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is can be possible with new framework by Apple - MusicKit. (but not sure)
https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/apple-music-best-practices-for-app-developers/